# React Native list view data parsing from JSON

Tags: react-native

This is the JSON im trying to parse and show in my list view.

[image]

The data I would like to show on my list view is ZoneInfo["Name"] as a section header. For the list view, there would be 3 text showing the Name,QueueTime or ShowTime.

I have my JSON saved in my state variable.

This is the code I've been trying to retrieve the data from the JSON.

```
{this.state.loading? <Spinner /> : <List dataArray={this.state.results.items} renderRow={(item) =>
    <ListItem>
      <Text>{item}</Text>
    </ListItem>
} />}
```

Anyone can guide me on how I can parse the JSON and show it on my listview?

Answer (score 0):

There are for sure multiple ways of achieving this, up till now I'm pretty happy using it this way:

I'm sure you will find your way around ;-)

```
export default class extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);
    this.renderSectionHeader = this.renderSectionHeader.bind(this);


    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
    sectionHeaderHasChanged: (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2});    

    this.state = {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections({}),

    };

}

componentDidMount(){
    ... load your json and assign data to the state

    this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRowsAndSections(spots)
        });
}

renderRow(rowData: string, sectionID: number, rowID: number) {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.onRowPress(rowData)}>
        ... your row content
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}


renderSectionHeader(sectionData, category) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.rowHeaderContainer}>
        ... your header content
    </View>
  )
}

render(){
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ListView                     
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderRow}
                enableEmptySections={true}
                renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
            />
      </View>
    );
}
}
```